# Wrong search in A* pathing code

Tags: c++, a-star, path-finding

I have some C++ code I wrote to find an A* path, but it's behaving strangely. There's quite a bit of code here, so I'll split it into chunks and try to explain what I'm doing. I'm not gonna explain how A* pathing works. I assume if you're trying to help you already know the algorithm.

First off, here's my function for calculating the h value of a node:

```
int
calculateH(int cX, int cY, int eX, int eY, int horiCost = 10, int diagCost = 14) {
int h;
int xDist = abs(eX - cX);
int yDist = abs(eY - cY);

if (xDist > yDist)
    h = (diagCost * yDist) + (horiCost * (xDist - yDist));
else
    h = (diagCost * xDist) + (horiCost * (yDist - xDist));

return h;
}
```

I'm pretty sure there's no problem here; pretty simple stuff.

Next my Node class. And I know, I know, make those variables private and use getters; I just did it this way for testing purposes.

```
class Node {
public:
Node(int x_, int y_, int g_, int h_, int pX_, int pY_, bool list_) {
    x = x_;
    y = y_;
    g = g_;
    h = h_;
    pX = pX_;
    pY = pY_;
    list = list_;
};
int x, y, g, h, pX, pY;
bool list;
};
```

Each Node has an X and Y variable. I only store G and H, not F, and calculate F when I need it (which is only once in my code). Then there's the Parent X and Y values. List is a boolean: fale = open list, true = closed list.

I also have a Object class. The only variables that matter here are X, Y, and Passable, all accessed through getters.
Now here's the start of my actual pathfinding code. It returns a string of numbers corresponding to directions as shown below:
432
501
678
So 1 means move right, 8 means go down and right, 0 means don't go anywhere.

```
string
findPath(int startX, int startY, int finishX, int finishY) {
// Check if we're already there.
if (startX == finishX && startY == finishY)
    return "0";
// Check if the space is occupied.
for (int k = 0; k < objects.size(); k ++)
    if ((objects[k] -> getX() == finishX) &&
        (objects[k] -> getY() == finishY) &&
        (!objects[k] -> canPass()))
        return "0";
// The string that contains our path.
string path = "";
// The identifier of the current node.
int currentNode = 0;
// The list of nodes.
vector<Node> nodes;
// Add the starting node to the closed list.
nodes.push_back(Node(startX, startY, 0,
    calculateH(startX, startY, finishX, finishY),
    startX, startY, true));
```

Now we loop through until we find the destination. Note that sizeLimit is just to make sure we don't loop forever (it WONT if I can fix this code. As of right now it's very necessary). Everything from this point on, until I mark otherwise, is inside the i j loops.

```
int sizeLimit = 0;
while ((nodes[currentNode].x != finishX) | (nodes[currentNode].y != finishY)) {

    // Check the surrounding spaces.
    for (int i = -1;  i <= 1; i ++) {
        for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j ++) {
            bool isEmpty = true;
            // Check if there's a wall there.
            for (int k = 0; k < objects.size(); k ++) {
                if ((objects[k] -> getX() == (nodes[currentNode].x + i)) &&
                    (objects[k] -> getY() == (nodes[currentNode].y + j)) &&
                    (!objects[k] -> canPass())) {
                    isEmpty = false;
                }
            }
```

Next part:

```
 // Check if it's on the closed list.
            for (int k = 0; k < nodes.size(); k ++) {
                if ((nodes[k].x == (nodes[currentNode].x + i)) &&
                    (nodes[k].y == (nodes[currentNode].y + j)) &&
                    (nodes[k].list)) {
                    isEmpty = false;
                }
            }
```

Continuing on:

```
// Check if it's on the open list.
            for (int k = 0; k < nodes.size(); k ++) {
                if ((nodes[k].x == (nodes[currentNode].x + i)) &&
                    (nodes[k].y == (nodes[currentNode].y + j)) &&
                    (!nodes[k].list)) {
                    // Check if the G score is lower from here.
                    if (nodes[currentNode].g + 10 + (abs(i * j) * 4) <= nodes[k].g) {
                        nodes[k].g = nodes[currentNode].g + 10 + (abs(i * j) * 4);
                        nodes[k].pX = nodes[currentNode].x;
                        nodes[k].pY = nodes[currentNode].y;
                    }
                    isEmpty = false;
                }
            }
```

This is the last part of the i j loop:

```
if (isEmpty) {
                nodes.push_back(Node(nodes[currentNode].x + i,
                    nodes[currentNode].y + j,
                    nodes[currentNode].g + 10 + (abs(i * j) * 4),
                    calculateH(nodes[currentNode].x + i, nodes[currentNode].y + j, finishX, finishY),
                    nodes[currentNode].x,
                    nodes[currentNode].y,
                    false));
            }
    }
}
```

Now we find the Node with the lowest F score, change it to the current node, and add it to the closed list. The protection against infinite lopping is also finished up here:

```
// Set the current node to the one with the lowest F score.
    int lowestF = (nodes[currentNode].g + nodes[currentNode].h);
    int lowestFIndex = currentNode;
    for (int k = 0; k < nodes.size(); k ++) {
        if (((nodes[k].g + nodes[k].h) <= lowestF) &&
            (!nodes[k].list)) {
            lowestF = (nodes[k].g + nodes[k].h);
            lowestFIndex = k;
        }
    }
    currentNode = lowestFIndex;
    // Change it to the closed list.
    nodes[currentNode].list = true;

    sizeLimit ++;
    if (sizeLimit > 1000)
        return "";
}
```

The problem I'm having is that it wont find *certain* paths. It seems to never work if the path goes up or left at any point. Down, left, and right all work fine. Most of the time anyway. I have absolutely no idea what's causing this problem; at one point I even tried *manually* following my code to see where the problem was. No surprise that didn't work.

And one more thing: if you're counting my curly braces (first of all wow, you have more dedication than I thought), you'll notice I'm missing a close brace at the end. Not to mention my return statement. There's a little bit of code at the end to actually make the path that I've left out. I know that that part's not the problem however; I currently have it commented out and it still doesn't work in the same way. I added some code to tell me where it's not working, and it's at the pathfinding part, not the interpretation.

Sorry my code's so messy and inefficient. I'm new to c++, so any critical advice on my technique is welcome as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that when you are looking for the next "currentNode", you should not start with `lowestF = (nodes[currentNode].g + nodes[currentNode].h);` because that value, in principle, will (always) be lower-or-equal-to any other nodes in the open-set. Just start with the value of `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` or some very large number, or use a priority queue instead of an `std::vector` to store the nodes (like `std::priority_queue`, or `boost::d_ary_heap_indirect`).

I'm pretty sure that is the problem. And since your heuristic can very often be equal to the actual path-distance obtained, there is a good chance that following nodes in the open-set turn out to have the same cost (g+h) as the currentNode. This would explain why certain paths get explored and others don't and why it gets stuck.

Comment: Again I'm amazed by the pomptness and helpfulness of the answers on this site. I knew it was something small; I just needed another set of eyes to pick it out. And thanks for pointing me in the direction of 'std::priority_queue' and 'boost::d_ary_heap_inderect'. Being new to C++ I often get too comfortable with one method or another; it's good to be shown other ways of doing things. Thanks again - Seymore